# Contact form 7 and amazon SES

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

Is there a way to set up contact form 7 with amazon SES? 
On my server I have an issue that not allow to use SMTP. And I use Amazon SES to send newsletter emails. It works, but when I install contact form, the form does not work. So I want to use amazon SES with the contact form. Can you tell me how I can do that, please? Thanks